# Using ffmpeg to create a contact sheet -- with a "logo"/info image inserted?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have figured out how to make a contact sheet in the way I want with ffmpeg. However, I'd like to be able to add a JPEG/PNG/whatever as the first image in the contact sheet. I don't have to use FFMPEG to do it, but it seems it'd be possible.

Here's what I have (that works):

ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf select=not(mod(n\,120)),scale=800:-1,tile=1x4 -vsync 0 in-grid.jpg

If it's currently in a 1x4 format, then the first of the 4 would be the jpeg/png "logo"/header.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below requires that the logo have the same resolution as the video.

```
ffmpeg -i logo -i test.mp4 -filter_complex [0][1]concat,select='eq(n,0)+not(mod(n-1,120))',scale=800:-1,tile=1x4 -vsync 0 in-grid.jpg
```